# Reading Intel Matrix Storage Manager (Intel fakeRAID) metadata on a non-Intel controller with mdadm

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

In a few months, I will be swapping out the motherboard of a system which has IMSM (Intel Matrix Storage Manager, or Intel's version of fake RAID) configured with RAID 1 on two 1TB disks.

The replacement motherboard however will use AMD's X470 chipset, hence a very different controller.

I know that of course the data won't be compatible, but I was wondering if one could (on Linux) still access it somehow: as I was able to do so with an ancient hardware RAID card in the past, I assume it would be possible, but my initial searches have not been successful.

Can I use `mdadm` to read the disks correctly on non Intel hardware?

Comment: A nice theoretical question. But given that you seem to want to keep the data I assume that you hve backups (not just for the sake of testing, but also because you will be testing non standard things with your main disks). So why not simply restore the data from that backup?

Comment: Granted, above comment would be the practical thing. I am still curious to see if it would just work or if there are any catches. So upvoted.

Comment: @Hennes Yes, I have backups done daily on two different locations. It's to reduce hassle, mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out. A fairly recent mdadm *is* able to do so provided that the environment variable `IMSM_NO_PLATFORM` is set to 1. In fact my openSUSE system did not even need that, and loaded the array automagically.